# Add the sum of array values to hash (map / grep)

Tags: perl, sum, hashmap

I've been trying to figure out this one-liner, and can't seem to get it to work.

Say I have this reference to an array of hashrefs:

```
my $payments = [
   {
      'receipt_id'     => '100',
      'payment_id'     => '1',
      'payment_amount' => 20,
   },
   {
      'receipt_id'     => '100',
      'payment_id'     => '1',
      'payment_amount' => 30,
   },
   {
      'receipt_id'     => '100',
      'payment_id'     => '2',
      'payment_amount' => 40,
   },
   {
      'receipt_id'     => '200',
      'payment_id'     => '1',
      'payment_amount' => 20,
   },
];
```

What I'd like to do is create a hash where the key is the payment_id, and the value is the sum of all payment_amounts for a particular receipt_id.

I can do:

```
my %sum_payments = map  { $_->{payment_id} => $_->{payment_amount} }
                   grep { $_->{receipt_id} eq '100' }
                   @$payments;
```

And get:

```
1 => 30,
2 => 40,
```

But when I try:

```
my %sum_payments = map  { $_->{payment_id} => (sum map { $_->{payment_amount} }) }
                   grep { $_->{receipt_id} eq '100' }
                   @$payments;
```

It throws errors.

How can I write a one-liner using map / grep to get:

```
1 => 50,
2 => 40,
```

Also, I know there are many other ways to achieve the same thing. I'm interested to know if this is possible using a single statement with map / grep.

Comment: What is the error? And where `sum` is defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need something to accumulate into - such as assigning directly into the destination hash:

```
my %sum_payments;

map { $sum_payments{$_->{payment_id}} += $_->{payment_amount} }
grep { $_->{receipt_id} eq '100' }
@$payments;
```

This is similar to @toolic's answer but, as that says, less readable (and I think less inefficient on large input due to grep building an intermediate list), and some people don't like `map` used like this.

Comment: Though a foreach would usually be used: `$sum_payments{$_->{payment_id}} += $_->{payment_amount} for grep ...`

Comment: `grep` doesn't really build an additional list. It just moves C pointers from one stack (an array) to another. Quite efficient.

Comment: @ikegami good to know. I wasn't sure. Presumably still slower (and more memory?) than just using "if" directly?

Comment: @ikegami I was trying to retain the original code structure. I don't think people should use my code.

Comment: @jhnc, nice job! This is exactly what I was looking for. Uses map + grep, and correctly puts the sum of the payment amounts into a hash with the payment_id as the key.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the approach you are trying is that to calculate the sum with a function like that requires you to somehow build up a list for each `payment_id` before you pass it to the function.  It may be possible to do this all in one line, but I think it is much more straightforward to use a `for` loop in this case:

```
my %sum_payments;
for (@{ $payments }) {
    if ($_->{receipt_id} eq '100') {
        $sum_payments{ $_->{payment_id} } += $_->{payment_amount};        
    }
}
```

Output:

```
      '1' => 50,
      '2' => 40
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit unsure of the exact requirements but I take it that the complete result would be

```
payment_id      receipt_id     sum of amounts
1           =>  100        =>  50  (20+30)
                200        =>  20
2           =>  100        =>  40
```

Then

```
my %recd;
for my $hr (@$payments) {
    $recd{$hr->{payment_id}}{$hr->{receipt_id}} += $hr->{payment_amount}
}

dd \%recd;  # w/ use Data::Dump;  Or use core Data::Dumper
```

Prints

```
{ 1 => { 100 => 50, 200 => 20 }, 2 => { 100 => 40 } }
```

For each id there are keys of all receipts, each having for a value the total amounts.

Still not sure why `receipt_id` of `100` is singled out in the question (and all answers) ... because the idea is that only one is needed in each run of the program?  If that is so then this answer is an overkill; use some of the others.

On the other hand, it's plausible that there'll be further needs and why not build it with all data. Then the specific ones can be plucked out as needed, by a direct lookup.

---

The specific `map`+`grep` attempt from the question won't work because `map` in each iteration has one record (hashref) on hand so it can't simply sum up `payment_amount` across all of them.

So I think that no, one can't reasonably have that (other than by some bad acrobatics formally cast in a single statement eventually assigning to a hash, that is).

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`reduce` from the standard `List::Util` module](https://perldoc.perl.org/List::Util#reduce) to compute the values in a single pass over your arrayref using a [fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw/reduce/;
use Data::Dumper;

my $payments =
  [
   {
    'receipt_id'     => '100',
    'payment_id'     => '1',
    'payment_amount' => 20,
   },
   {
    'receipt_id'     => '100',
    'payment_id'     => '1',
    'payment_amount' => 30,
   },
   {
    'receipt_id'     => '100',
    'payment_id'     => '2',
    'payment_amount' => 40,
   },
   {
    'receipt_id'     => '200',
    'payment_id'     => '1',
    'payment_amount' => 20,
   },
  ];

# Results in a hashref
my $sum_payments =
  reduce {
    if ($b->{receipt_id} eq '100') {
      $a->{$b->{payment_id}} += $b->{payment_amount};
    }
    $a
  } {}, @$payments;

print Dumper($sum_payments);
```

prints out

```perl
$VAR1 = {
          '1' => 50,
          '2' => 40
        };
```

Comment: Technically not map + grep, but still a single expression in the functional spirit unlike an explicit loop (Generally a fold/reduce can replace either or both map and filter/grep).

Comment: You could still use grep here. `reduce { $a->{$b->{payment_id}} += $b->{payment_amount} } {}, grep { $_->{receipt_id} eq '100' };`

Comment: @ikegami You *could*, but you *shouldn't*, as that requires an unnecessary second pass over the data (much like `grep ... | awk ...` is a poor design in a shell script).

Comment: Plus that modified `reduce` block won't work. Needs to return `$a`.

Comment: I have no idea where you got the idea that it's poor design in shell script. It's not. Chaining tools like that is a fundamental aspect of unix. // And we're not launching programs here. You are doing exactly the same amount of work both ways. There's no magical extra pass like you claim. That's made up. Quite the opposite, your version isn't only less clean, it's slower since it involves more sub calls. // Yes, the `$a` is missing. That wasn't the point; that was a typo.

Comment: No idea? It comes up all the time in the shell script related tags and other forums. Piping grep output to awk is considered poor practice because you can just do the filtering in awk. Similarly, chaining a filter and fold can be turned into just a fold because it can do the filtering part. Makes for less work overall.

Comment: I repeat. It's actually yours that does more work (uses more CPU). It's because your approach does so many more sub calls (N+1 of them, instead filtered+1)